# Unable to run SpringBoot 3+MyBatis with JDK17 command line

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, java-17

I'm experiencing a strange problem on a simple project with Spring Boot (v. 3.1.5), MyBatis and JDK17.

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.5</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

When running the application locally with my IDE it works without problems.
And it works also with command line using the command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

But I was not able to to run it using the command java

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

In this case a strange error on a mybatis map is prompted.
It seems that using this command it loads more than once the single mybatis map I'm using.

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'URL [jar:file:C:\Development\workspaces\sts\myapp\target\myjar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes/mybatis/mappers/Order.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains key myapp.repotracer.mapper.OrderMapper.mapper_resultMap[orderResultMap]_collection[sfcs]
```

The jar file contains just one XML file of the map.

Comment: If you could share a small demo project that reproduces the problem on GitHub, I would take a look when I have time. [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) are some project templates.

Comment: you can take this project here
https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples/mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml

Comment: The problem seems related to the fact that I'm not using the mybatis-config.xml file. If I define it like this

```
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.schindler.sceu.apps.repotracer.domain"/>
    </typeAliases>
    <mappers>
      <mapper resource="sample/mybatis/xml/mapper/CityMapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</mappers>
</configuration>
```

It will fails with above message (the first think I thought was that the map is loaded twice). 
But if I omit the <mapper> into the mybatis-config.xml everything works.

is it a mybatis bug?

Comment: Please read the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/index.html#advanced-scanning). mybatis-spring-boot will detect mappers (i.e. interface with `@Mapper` annotation) automatically. If there is `<mapper>` in  `mybatis-config.xml`, mappers will be loaded twice. When using mybatis-spring-boot, you should not use `mybatis-config.xml`. Use `application.properties` or Java config instead (it's explained in the doc).

Comment: Just to be clear, it is not a bug.

Comment: As I said I'm not using the mybatis-config.xml file!
And the project works if I launch it from my IDE.
But if I run it from command line (or from a docker) the error is prompted.

I've solved the problem by adding an empty mybatis-config.xml file without any mappers.

I don't think it is the right solution.

The problem does not occur with previous versions of mybatis spring boot (< 3)

Comment: Well...please provide a demo project (the project you linked is the sample project in the official repo, not yours). Without reproducing the problem, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I am running into the same issue while upgrading to spring 3 and jdk17.everything working fine from IDE,as soon as I deploy to cluster using jar it breaks